# AG-Grid: updated row data is not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, ag-grid-react

While using AG-Grid table, latest updated data is not rendering in the table. I have to use either setTimeout method or resolve that promise to get the updated row data from backend. What should be the best solution to resolve this?

Whenever I'm trying to fetch row data from backend, then at the first time it's showing no data. But when I make some changes in the table and try to call that data again in setTimeout method, then it's working fine.

Expectation: It should render the updated data without any promise resolve.